# Check if 1/3 Queries Evaluates to True

Tags: oracle

My large (+100 line) query contains a `WHERE` filter similar to:

```
select * 
from (<complex 100+ line query>) d 
WHERE (
   (EXISTS (select 1 FROM TABLE1 t1 
            WHERE d.dummy = t1.x 
              AND t1.col1 = 'FOOBAR' AND t1.col2 IN ('A', ))) OR 
   (EXISTS (select 1 FROM TABLE2 t2 
            WHERE d.dummy = t2.x 
              AND t2.col1 = 'FOOBAR' AND t2.col2 IN ('A', 'B'))) OR
   (EXISTS (select 1 FROM TABLE3 t3 
            WHERE d.dummy = t3.x 
              AND t3.col1 = 'FOOBAR' AND t3.col2 IN ('A', 'B')))
)
```

Prior to this "type" of change, i.e. 3 `EXISTS`, the query ran in 1-3 seconds. However, with the above "type" of addition (as a `WHERE` filter, the query has ground to a halt - 60 seconds.

I've looked at the EXPLAIN PLAN, but I don't understand the output.

Basically, I only want to show the row from `<query> d` if its `dummy` column matches one of the `x` columns of `TABLE1`, `TABLE2`, or `TABLE3`.

From a performance and good SQL practice point-of-view, is the above `WHERE` inner query a reasonable way to determine if at least 1/3 conditions is true?

Comment: Updated the wording - my mistake if I was unclear.

Comment: Updated my **unclear** question again. Hopefully it's a better description of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: To clarify, in your actual query the DUAL d is an actual table or view and the three EXISTS predicates are correlated to it via one of its columns, and it's the same column in all three cases, correct?

Comment: `in your actual query the DUAL d is an actual table or view and the three EXISTS predicates are correlated to it via one of its columns, and it's the same column in all three cases` Mostly correct - I just updated the question.

Comment: What indexes (if any) are on `TABLE1`, `TABLE2` and `TABLE3`? If not, column "x" or "col1", it may be a bit slow. You could try UNION ALL those 3 tables within a single EXISTS :) *might* help ..

Comment: I've edited your question (and hopefully fixed some mismatching parentheses near the EXISTS / OR subqueries)

Comment: @Ditto, looking at the PLAN output, I see that each of the 3 `EXISTS ...` uses `INDEX FULL SCAN`, using an index on 4 columns: `col1`, `col2`, `x`, and another column.

Comment: @kevin: ok, that seems weird it would do an `INDEX FULL SCAN` with those indexes - unless perhaps stats are stale ?  But if you have those indexes on it, then putting them into a single `EXISTS` using a `UNION ALL` might work - try it. See how the explain looks when you do that. ;)

Comment: oddly, I replaced my `(EXISTS ... )` statements with: `d.dummy IN (select TableName.x FROM TableName t WHERE t.col1 = 'FOOBAR' AND t.col2 IN ('A', 'B'))))` - and it takes only 4 seconds to run, compared to 50 seconds before.

Comment: As I partially understand the terminology, I replaced my `correlated sub-query` with a `noncorrelated sub-query`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `t3.x` is indexed.

If you know one test is much cheaper than another, it may be faster to `JOIN` them in a manner that makes sense, then use the `/*+ORDERED*/` hint to force the optimizer to join them in the order you've written them. This is particularly necessary if your inner query contains REGEX expressions since the optimizer prefers to procrastinate evaluating them.